# Error with function transactional function in neo4j and SDN

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Dears, we're experiencing some random issue with our Neo4J 4.2 Enterprise cluster and a bunch of Spring-based applications.
We're using SDN6 and reactive sessions to run custom queries on our cluster but sometimes we get this error

```
Message 'COMMIT' cannot be handled by a session in the READY state.
```

both on db side and on application.
We're currently using transactional functions to leverage on the retry logic as explained [here](https://medium.com/neo4j/try-and-then-retry-there-can-be-failure-30bf336383da)

Any ideas?
Best,
FB

Comment: Can you add the exact version of SDN you are using, as well as the code that may cause this (if applicable)?

Comment: Wild guess: Are you mixing up `@Transactional` with Java driver's transactional functions? This might not end well because you would suddenly have two transactions running.